# Function to check if user is allowed to do something and if no get reason why

Tags: java

I need to check if user is allowed to cancel appointment. Right now i first call service method which return boolean and if it is false then I call another method which returns reason in String. It is working but I think it's ugly. Do you have any ideas how can I improve this? Or maybe this approach is okay?

AppointmentService:

```
 public boolean isUserAllowedToCancelAppointment(int userId, int appointmentId) {
        User user = userService.findById(userId);
        Appointment appointment = findById(appointmentId);

        // only scheduled appointments can be canceled
        if(!appointment.getStatus().equals("scheduled")){
            return false;
        }
        // other conditions...
}


 public String getCancelNotAllowedReason(int userId, int appointmentId) {
        User user = userService.findById(userId);
        Appointment appointment = findById(appointmentId);

        if(!appointment.getStatus().equals("scheduled")){
            return "status";
        // other conditions and reasons...
}
```

Controller:

```
   @GetMapping("/{id}")
   public String showAppointmentDetail(@PathVariable("id") int appointmentId, Model model, @AuthenticationPrincipal CustomUserDetails currentUser) {

    if (appointmentService.isUserAllowedToCancelAppointment(currentUser.getId(), appointmentId)) {
        model.addAttribute("allowCancel", true);
    } else {
        model.addAttribute("allowCancel", false);
        model.addAttribute("cancelNotAllowedReason", appointmentService.getCancelNotAllowedReason(currentUser.getId(), appointmentId));
    }
   }
```

Comment: I think this question should be migrated to [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an `enum` of possible issues:

```
enum Issue {TOO_LATE, NOT_SCHEDULED, ... }
```

And then create a single validation method which returns a `Set<Issue>`:

```
public Set<Issue> validate(int userId, int appointmentId) { ... }
```

Then you can check the different cases and if they apply add the `Issue` to the set:

```
Set<Issue> issues = EnumSet.noneOf(Issue.class);
if( not scheduled ) {
    issues.add(Issue.NOT_SCHEDULED);
}
if( too late ) {
    issues.add(Issue.TOO_LATE);
}
return issues;
```

Then at the call site you can check if `issues.isEmpty()`:

```
Set<Issue> issues = appointmentService.validate(userId, appointmentId);
model.addAttribute("allowCancel", issues.isEmpty());
model.addAttribute("cancelNotAllowedReason", issues);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making two calls, while you should only make one.
This is indeed not recommended.

Drop the boolean method, and keep something like:

```
public String getCancelNotAllowedReason(int userId, int appointmentId) {
        User user = userService.findById(userId);
        Appointment appointment = findById(appointmentId);

        if(!appointment.getStatus().equals("scheduled")){
            return "not yet scheduled";
        }
        if ( appointment.isDateTooClose()) {
           return "Too late to cancel";
        }
        // other conditions and reasons...
        return "Valid";
}
```

In the calling class:

```
if ( service.getCancellNotAllowedReason(1, 1).equals("Valid")) {
  //cancel
} else {
  // show information message
}
```

It might be better, though, to return a `List<String>` of reasons. Otherwise, your client might fix the first issue, and assume he can cancel than, just to get stuck on the next issue.

Answer (score 0):

`getCancelNotAllowedReason()` can simply return `null` when a cancel is allowed. No need for a separate check function.

```
  String reason = appointmentService.getCancelNotAllowedReason(currentUser.getId(), appointmentId);
  model.addAttribute("allowCancel", reason == null);
  model.addAttribute("cancelNotAllowedReason", reason);
```